# Open Comment Reply Form On Button Click

Tags: javascript, button, blogs, reply

I have a blog that has a reply form for each comment on the blog. I am trying to create a "Reply" button that would show the form once its clicked. Right now, if I click any "Reply" button it will only apply the hide style to the first button and the block style to the first div.

HTML

```
<div class="reply">
  <button id="replybutton" onclick="replybutton()">Click Me</button>
  <div id="replyform">
    <form>
      ...
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

HTML

```
function replybutton() {
  document.getElementById("replyform").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("replybutton").style.display = "none";
enter code here
```

Comment: I think you have more than 1 item with the same identifier. Try using unique Ids for each button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The id are supposed to be unique. So each form should have a unique id. You can use a common class to show/hide them.

When you click a button you should pass its reference to your `onClick` function like this `onclick="replybutton(this)` and modify your onClick function to target the button `function replybutton(btn)`. If you want to show/hide your form you can use the `nextElementSibling`

See the jsFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/th4dz1q0/2/